# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, windows-phone

```
public bool ReadFile()
    {

        string fname = "text.txt";
        FileStream fs = null;
        fs = new FileStream(fname, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
        string res = sr.ReadToEnd();
        if (res == "1")
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

public void WriteToFile()
    {
        string fname = "text.txt";
        FileStream fs = null;
        fs = new FileStream(fname, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        sw.Write("1");
    }
```

So it should work like if ReadFile returns false than i do WriteFile.
But when it reaches writefile, it throws IO expection:

The process cannot access the file ... because it is being used by another process

Comment: try close an dispose streams

Comment: Here's a tip: When you say `if (res == "1")
        return true;
    else
        return false;`, you're actually saying `if (true) return true; else return false;`. See the redudency? Instead, you can just say `return res == 1";` and have the same effect, but its a bit cleaner (;

Answer (score 3):

You aren't closing the file when you read it.

Put your FileStream and StreamReader objects in using statements:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(fname, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.Read)) {
  using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs)) {
    //read file here
  }
}
```

Make sure you do the same when you write to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dispose the StreamReader object in the ReadFile method. The StreamReader inherits from IDisposable and therfor you need to dispose the object.

Check this link for more info:[StreamReader Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx)